# add a column to an existing table

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm wanting the best way to add a column to an existing table in my database.  I'm using `SQL Server 2012`. I don't want the data that is in the table to be affected, I just want to add a new column that has a default value of `NULL`.  The only ways I'm aware of for adding a new column is by using:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable ADD newColumn VARCHAR(20) NULL;
```

and the other way of adding a new column is by going into `SQL Server Management Studio`, bringing up the `Design` for the table I want to update, and adding the new column's information to the design.

Comment: The T-SQL statement is the best way to add a new column

Comment: Use `ALTER TABLE` - SSMS will find all kinds of ways to drop and re-create your table if you start clicking around in their crappy visual designers...

Comment: How about just reading Microsoft document and see examples mentioned http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190273.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no *"BEST"* way to add a column. There is only one way - using the T-SQL command. What do you think happens when you use SSMS table design? it's just a way to simplify tasks for those who don't know the syntax. When you click OK, SSMS generates the `ALTER TABLE` statement and executes it for you.